# Thunderbid misses inline attachments when filtering by attachments

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird can filter by whether an email contains an attachment:

[image]

Some people attach inline, others prefer non-inline attachments.
However, TB only filters emails that contain non-inline attachments.
The ones containing inline attachments don't show up.
That's kinda.. weird?

Can I make it filter emails with attachments in general, no matter whether they're inline or not?

Comment: You mean embedded images? “inline” seems to be an odd way to describe that.

Comment: That's what it's called though, [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351465/html-email-with-inline-attachments-and-non-inline-attachments).